# Asp.Net Core - multiple action methods with the same name and different parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm looking for a way to have more than one action method with the same name in controller without changing Url (route).

```cs
[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult Method1 (Dto1 param)
{
}

[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult Method2 (Dto2 param)
{
}

[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult Method3 (Dto3 param)
{
}
```

This throws error -

> *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints*

Dto1, Dto2 and Dto3 derive from a base Dto, each have properties specific to different request methods. I am trying to avoid having a single method with a common Dto which will require multiple validations such as validating mandatory fields based on the value of other fields, etc. If we can have 3 different Post methods with different Dtos, it would makes things much easier

Adding Dtos (Simplified)

```
public class BaseDto
{
    public string CommonProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class Dto1: BaseDto
{
    public enumType Type = enumType.Type1;
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Dto2 : BaseDto
{
    public enumType Type = enumType.Type2;
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Dto3 : BaseDto
{
    public enumType Type = enumType.Type3;
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your `Dto1`, `Dto2`, `Dto3` and `base Dto` classes

Comment: You shouldn't do this as the way you want, and it's has no logic to do this.

Comment: How can the server *guess* which action to call by looking at the URL? An HTTP request has no type beyond that specified by the `Content-Type` header. If the *client* uses a different content-type, you can specify conditions to call different actions

Comment: `Dto1, Dto2 and Dto3 derive from a base Dto` in that case why use multiple actions? Use one action and call the appropriate code/method based on the DTO's type. In older c# versions you can use `is` or `as. In C# 7 and later you can use pattern matching

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How would model binding work in this case?

Comment: @Leandro The reason I want to do that is to avoid to many validations of the request if I use a single action method with a common dto. I have posted simplified dtos, but thee are more properties and many properties are mandatory based on the the type. I thought having different methods with request-specific dtos will make validations simpler - model binding can handle most of it

Comment: @bdotnet see the update of my answer

Comment: Thanks @Leandro. How does the caller send both parameters? Ex. caller sends BaseDto and Type=2. Type2 requires some more properties, where/how will they be sent?

Comment: @bdotnet how are you making the post? Or you can create a new object with that two properties (not an herency)

Comment: @Leandro one of the sample requests (matches Dto1) is :  {
    "CommonProp1": "value",
    "CommonProp2": "value",
    "Type": "value",
    "Property1 ": "value"
}

Comment: Using Public ActionResult Method (BaseDto param, int type)  does not help because first param is the same irrespective of the second param (type). Based on the type, Dtos change though they have some common properties from baseDto

Comment: @bdotnet because you are sending Dto1, you have to send BaseDto and those properties in separated. In any case, I remember you, you are doing a workaround, this is not the way you work with herachy

Comment: Finally I decided to have one action method and one Dto (dto1+dto2+dto3). Caller will send one of the Dtos based on the type and all validations will be performed to ensure input for each type is valid. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Routes or calling a private method from the three above methods, you shouldn't do this as you want. I think your problem is more deep.

But.... if you still want it, here is a workaround.

Instead of receiving an object, receive a string with json content and parse the object.

But you will have to have a property inside the "json object" or another parameter that defines you wich object it is (Dto1, Dto2 or Dto3). In any case will be the same that use different routes or methods because objects are different.

```
[HTTPPost]

Public ActionResult Method (string param)
{

//Decode your string called param with JSON with a property inside

}
```

or

```
[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult Method (string param, int type)
{

//Decode your string called param with JSON switching "type" as 1, 2 or 3

}
```

UPDATE after your update:

I suggest you receive BaseDto and the type in other parameter.

```
[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult Method (BaseDto param, int type)
{
 

}
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep, you are right, I think it but I didn't write it. In any case is a little workaround for do something that shouldn't be done (as I commented previously)